# YUI autocomplete ......... need to change z-index value from javascript

Tags: javascript, yui

I am new to YUI and I am doing some SugarCRM PHP modifications. I need to change my z-index on this class

.yui3-aclist { z-index: 100; }

HOW CAN I DO THIS FROM JAVASCRIPT / YUI ???

The API doens't allow me access to the .css files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting zIndex won't actually do anything, because the AutoCompleteList doesn't inherit from WidgetStack (since YUI 3.4.0, anyway).

Instead, you can set it directly on the bounding box of the AutoComplete plugin:

```
var node = Y.one('#ac-input');
node.plug( Y.Plugin.AutoComplete, { ... });
node.ac.get('boundingBox').setStyle('zIndex', 50);
```

You can see a working example here:

http://jsbin.com/amayux/1/edit